# Opening files in html

Tags: html, file

```
  <form> 

  <p><b>Room Number:</b></p> 

  <form action="action_page.php">
  <select name="rooms">
  <option value="select">Select a Room</option>
  <option value="room 1">Room 0001</option>
  <option value="room 2">Room 0002</option>
  <option value="room 3">Room 0003</option>
  <option value="room 4">Room 0004</option>
  </select> 
  </form>
```

How can I implement that by opening a text file and getting the values "room 0001-0004 and not writing them at the html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this, and worked... Just in case anyone ever need it :P

```
<p><b>Room Number:</b></p>                  
<form>
<select name="rooms">
<option value="select">Select a Room</option>
 <?php $i = 0;
label:
 ?>
<option value="<?=$csvArray[$i];?>" ><?=$csvArray[$i];?></option>
<?php 
if($i<count($csvArray)-1){
    $i++;
    goto label;
}
?>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is incredibly generic. But a language like PHP is ideally designed to be a web development language, and it suited to this application. Assuming that the file extension was changed to `.phtml` and an appropriate server had been set up [please see this link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_install.asp) (note I don't normally use w3 schools, but I think its appropriate here). It would be possible to modify the now phtml file as so:

```
<?php
    $fileHandle = fopen("filename.csv", "r");
    $csvArray = fgetcsv($fileHandle);
?>

/** Normal HTML headers and the like! **/

<p><b>Room Number:</b></p> 

<form action="action_page.php">
    <select name="rooms">
      <option value="select">Select a Room</option>
      <option value="room 1">Room 0001</option>
      <option value="room 2">Room 0002</option>
      <option value="room 3">Room 0003</option>
      <option value="room 4">Room 0004</option>
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($csvArray); $i++): ?>
          <option value="<?=$csvArray[$i];?>" >Room 000<?=$i;?></option>
    </select> 
</form>
```

As a javascript alternative could easily be done, but there are many considerations to be made in terms of format and location.

I'm almost positive that you're trying to ask if this can be done using purely HTML. I don't believe thats possible. Perhaps using PHP (as above), javascript and an XHR call (but you'd still need somewhere to put the file) this is possible. But I don't believe in pure HTML this can be done.